# MySQL: Allow both remote AND local connections

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

In my Ubuntu's `/etc/mysql/my.conf`, I have:

```
bind-address = 192.168.2.20  # My external IP
```

It works fine from remote, but when I want to connect locally, [the app that uses on MySQL](http://www.pentaho.com/) says: `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect`.

So when I want to work locally, I change `my.cnf` to:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

And it starts working locally, but then it doesn't work from remote anymore.

How to make MySQL accesible both from remote AND local?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Bind to more than one IP address?](http://serverfault.com/questions/139323/mysql-bind-to-more-than-one-ip-address)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just comment out `bind-address=` altogether. When you do that, it will bind to all addresses. Also make sure that you don't have `skip-networking` enabled in your my.cnf.

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help!

Comment: I have `bind-address` commented, no `skip-networking`, my user is defined as 'test3@%', I can connect with `mysql -h 192.168.0.51 -P 3306 -u test3 -D test3` and yet I can't connect with `localhost`.

Comment: @Adrien You need to create another user with the same name that can access to localhost

Answer (score 1):

I've JUST got it to work using the command line tools on the server and remotely via php. 
Along with making sure skip-networking was hashed out (and our firewall rubbish), what I had to do was:

1. Try the command line tool on the server hosting the db (e.g. `shell> mysql -h localhost -u root -p` then enter password)
2. Make a note of the / path it tries to connect from (ending with .sock)
3. Go into `my.cnf` and make sure in the `[client]` and `[mysqld]` sections that `socket=` contains the path you found in step 2.