# Can't connect to mysql remotely

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, networking, mysql

I am running an ubuntu server, which has a LAMP stack.
The problem is I can't access MySQL remotely.

I have uncommented the bind-address, in the my.cnf file, but this has no effect.

`netstat -tap | grep mysql` output is:

```
tcp        0      0 *:mysql                 *:*                     LISTEN      18079/mysqld    
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         localhost:45288         TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         localhost:45802         ESTABLISHED 18079/mysqld    
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         localhost:45286         TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:45802         localhost:mysql         ESTABLISHED 18134/sshd: root
tcp        0      0 localhost:45287         localhost:mysql         TIME_WAIT   -
```

I can't telnet the server on port 3306 either, although I have made sure that port 3306 is open, using this command:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Telnet output is:

```
Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Result of iptables -L -nv:

```
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306
```

Comment: You need to provide the complete list of your firewall rules. You may have another rule that is prohibiting access to mysql.

Comment: That `iptables` command is not a guarantee that port 3306 is now open.  Could you add the output of `iptables -L -nv`?

Comment: Have you the same result if you try your telnet command (with your public IP) from your server which hosts your mysql ?
Are you sure about your network interface name (for the iptables command)?

Comment: fire up your favorite sniffer (e.g. tcpdump).  Do you see incoming port 3306 traffic?

Comment: Added iptables -L -nv data to original question

Comment: The database runs locally, and it works fine for production, but we have a test database, which we can't access remotely.

Comment: Check also: [MySQL: Allow both remote AND local connections](http://serverfault.com/questions/171655/mysql-allow-both-remote-and-local-connections).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from iptables shows that it has never seen *any* traffic on port 3306. (at least since the last flush of the counters).

Something else is blocking that port before it reaches your box.  Call your hosting provider.

Comment: I'd check to see if you can connect via the address configured on eth0 first - if not that would confirm it was being blocked elsewhere.

Comment: Tried to tcpdump -i eth0 port 3306, no traffic coming. I guess this confirms that it was blocked somewhere else.

I'm currently waiting for a VMWare restart, which opens port 3306, I'll accept when I confirm it works.