# How to make my database accept external connections?

Tags: mysql

In `my.cnf` file I can find `#bind-address = 127.0.0.1`. Is changing it to `bind-address = %` will do the job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the **bind-address** and **skip-networking** options are not specified, MySQL listens by default on all interfaces, so you should just make sure that those 2 options are commented.

You can also force MySQL to listen on all interfaces *explicitly* by specifying:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

If you want to make it to listen to only 1 IP address, you can do this by:

```
bind-address = your.ip.addr.ess
```

You can also check [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/139323/mysql-bind-to-more-than-one-ip-address) for more information.

Comment: Its for my gameserver which stands on the same machine along with MySQL. Is it nesesary to even open it? Becaouse my previous host told me that he had to open it with "%".

Comment: If your game server is on the machine, you won't need to open configure MySQL to accept external connections. However you may need to tweak the hosts that your user is allowed to connect from.

Comment: - However you may need to tweak the hosts that your user is allowed to connect from - How to do it?

Comment: It's actually different if you have already created your database user or not. [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html) you may find some information how to create it properly.

Comment: Can you provide some links? Ive created database and user.