# Mysql bind-address local subnet only

Tags: mysql, local-area-network, localhost

I am trying to allow users on my local subnet to log into my MySQL server.

The server is running Ubuntu 23.10 and MySql version 0.0.35-0ubuntu0.213.10.1

The Clients are 2 iMacs with macos Sonoma 14.2.1 and a Windows 11 PC.

The ubuntu server is on my local subnet (192.168.1.0) but is also available via a public fixed IP address. All the clients are using MYSQL Workbench 8.0

I have blocked public access to the server (apart from HTTP) via my firewall. But my issue is giving access to to MySQL server to my local clients.

I have amended ***/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf*** and changed `bind-address = 127.00.0.1 to 0.0.0.0` making Mysqld listen on any subnet. But this does seem very secure but it does work.

I have tried using `bind-address = 192.168.1.xxx, 192.168.1.yyy, 192.1658.1.zzz` but when I try to restart the MySQL service I get the error message.

```
 **Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.**
 **See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysql.service" for details** With an exit code of 1.
```

Also I have tried `bind-address = 192.168.1.0` but this gives me the same error message. I would most grateful for any advice on how to limit the bind-address to just my local subnet or even just my three clients

Comment: You can only bind to addresses you actually have configured on the machine, or `0.0.0.0`. What exactly did not "work" with `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind MySQL server to more than one IP address?](https://serverfault.com/questions/139323/how-to-bind-mysql-server-to-more-than-one-ip-address)

Answer (score 2):

Bind doesn't work the way you think it does.

It says *which* network interface to bind to. It has to be a network interface configured on the machine.

0.0.0.0 is a special case, essentially saying *all* available interfaces.

It does not restrict traffic in any way, any IP can contact it on the interfaces it is listening. If you want to limit traffic, use a firewall.

Thus in your scenario bind to 0.0.0.0 will be fine; it will be no different from binding to the specific interface if you only have one.

Comment: To add to this, `ufw` on Ubuntu can be configured to only allow access to port 3306 from the local subnet of `192.168.1.0/24` or even to the IP addresses of the two iMacs and the Windows 11 PC if they are static/fixed addresses.

Comment: AH, Thank you,  that explains things nicely.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation, on which I added an HAproxy "buffer".
I can't say if this will work for you, but it should work.

I added HAproxy on the same host as the mysqld, and created a listener in HAproxy on port 33061 (instead of the default 3306)

```
ss -antlp;
#LISTEN    0         128          <PUBLIC_IP>:33061            0.0.0.0:*       users:(("haproxy",pid=32645,fd=12))
```

The config is like this...

```
listen mysql
  bind        <PUBLIC_IP>:33061
  mode        tcp
  option      tcplog
  acl         mysql_ip_OK src -f /etc/haproxy/whitelist.IPs
  tcp-request connection reject if !mysql_ip_OK
  server      mysql1 127.0.0.1:3306
```

and the "filter" is like this...

```
cat <<EOF> /etc/haproxy/whitelist.IPs`
192.168.1.xxx
192.168.1.yyy
192.168.1.zzz
EOF
```

Any connection attempt would theoretically be blocked if it isn't specifically listed in /etc/haproxy/whitelist.IPs
The clients then connect to <PUBLIC_IP>:33061 instead of <PUBLIC_IP>:3306 and you gain additional security

Comment: Why use haproxy when a rather simple firewall rule will do the same trick?

Comment: agreed @vidarlo - in my particular use-case the list of IPs included dynamic/public addresses, and it was easiest for me to do it via haproxy, but is probably overkill for this scenario. Just offering ideas/alternatives :)

Comment: Sadly this did not work for me.